# Google App Engine: Directed to Google Sites Instead for Domain Name

Tags: google-app-engine

Tried following the instructions here:

[How to use Google app engine with my own naked domain (not subdomain)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-domain-not-subdomain)

Where I can use my google app engine website with my own domain name however when setting it up, it seems to be showing my google app sites instead of my google app engine website... any idea of where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you detail the steps you went through? There are two separate ways to add a domain for an app - starting in the Apps control panel, or starting in the App Engine control panel - and several things you might have done wrong.

Also, make sure that you don't have anything else serving on the subdomain (eg, 'www') you want your app on.

Finally, note that App Engine doesn't support 'naked' domains - foo.com instead of www.foo.com. A subdomain is always required.

Comment: I think when I was setting up the Domain on Google, I typed in "www" to set it up which may have conflicted with what I am trying to do with google app engine. However I can't find where I specified www for Google Apps ?

Answer (score 0):

The app engine binding doesn't work while google app site is available.
So, disable google app site and it should work!

Comment: There's nothing prohibiting having sites and an app engine app on the same domain, as long as they use different subdomains.

Comment: You're right Nick, what I wanted to say, was that: by default when you register a new domain with google app, it binds www. to a default google website. To bind your app engine to www. , you have to unregister the google website