# Wildcard subdomain on google app engine, alternatives to godaddy domains

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I'm building an app on google app engine and have it set with wildcard subdomain mapping: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.html

Next, my domain name is through godaddy and I have specific CNAMEs created for each subdomain I want, such as www:
[How to use Google app engine with my own naked domain (not subdomain)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-domain-not-subdomain)

The problem I'm facing is that I want goDaddy to allow me to have a wildcard CNAME so that I can have any subdomain without having to specifically set the CNAME for it. Such as: ANYTHING.mysite.com

Everything I've researched on the intraweb by the googles has told me I'm out of luck if I wish to do this through godaddy. So what other alternatives do I have? I really like godaddy and all my projects are under one account, so I hate to put this one domain name under some other vendor, but what are my other options?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your only choice is to move your DNS hosting to a provider that supports wildcard CNAME records.

A couple of options:

- [DynDNS](http://www.dyndns.com/)
- [DNS Made Easy](http://www.dnsmadeeasy.com/)

Once you have the new DNS setup, [update your nameservers with GoDaddy](http://help.godaddy.com/article/664).

Answer (score 0):

Godaddy now support wildcard. I am currently using a wildcard for an app with heroku. I am even using a subdomain of subdomain. I set the CNAME like this `*.subdomain` then point it to the heroku app.