# Custom domain on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I'm trying to map my (naked) domain to an app.

I found this.

> I'd like to map my app to http://myurl.com (also known as a naked
>   domain).
>
> Due to recent changes, Google App Engine no longer supports mapping
>   your app  to a naked domain. If your domain registrar supports URL
>   redirects, you can  redirect from http://yourdomain.com  to your app,
>   which can be served from  domains like http://www.yourdomain.com or
>   http://appid.yourdomain.com.
>
> For instructions on how to configure a redirect for your Google Apps
>   domain,  please see the article on URL forwarding.

Now I'd like not to resort to redirection. I understand udacity.com is hosted on     appengine and they seem to use a naked domain.

So, I;m hoping this is just typical bad documentation or not updated. Does anybody have     any info on how Udacity solves this problem or how could I produce such a behaviour?

Comment: udacity.com redirects to www.udacity.com

Comment: Yea, I just noticed that a second ago -.-

Comment: The docs are pretty clear - you can't map naked domains. Google Apps now has support for doing the redirect for you, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Google app engine with my own domain (not subdomain)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-domain-not-subdomain)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK AppEngine cannot be map to a naked domain, you can have a proxy mapped on your naked domain they will proxy into the application.

What most applications do is use forward from the naked domain to www where the application is mapped. GoDaddy supports that GoogleApps supports that and various other free and paid DNS services support that.