# get appengine website without www

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, dns

Is there a way to set up an appengine web application to deploy on a website without making the user type in `www.url.com`?

I have it deployed to `www.url.com` but `url.com` does not work.

*Is this possible with appengine?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Google app engine with my own domain (not subdomain)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-domain-not-subdomain)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914237/custom-domain-on-google-app-engine

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AppEngine does not currently support naked domains.

The best that you can do right now is set up your naked domain name to automatically redirect to the www. version.

Useful Links:

[Google Code Issue](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=777) requesting support for Naked Domains

[Nick Johnson's explanation](http://blog.notdot.net/2009/12/Naked-domains-on-App-Engine) for why the restriction exists