# Multiple Domains for Google app engine site - Analytics for each domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, google-analytics

Ok, so basically I am testing out a new marketing idea for the company I work for, buying 10 or so domains with key search words relating to the business (e.g carservice.com carmot.com hondaservice.com) and linking them all to one site, hosted on google app engine. I have got this bit to work but I now want to get google analytics to show how many people clicked on each domain so I know if its worth renewing. If no one visits it, its not worth paying for.
Is there a way I can send each domain to a different page hosted on the same app engine account? that way I could send it to a page which has a analytic code unique to the domain and then redirect it to the main site.

Thanks

Comment: Exact duplicate, even almost word-for-word in description, of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12164710/analytics-for-multiple-domains-google-app-engine-hosted-site

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Google app engine with my own domain (not subdomain)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-domain-not-subdomain)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're dynamically generating your pages, you can check the request URL for the domain and insert the appropriate Google Analytics token in the page before serving it.