# Analytics for multiple domains - Google App engine hosted site

Tags: google-app-engine, google-analytics, subdomain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple Domains for Google app engine site - Analytics for each domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159060/multiple-domains-for-google-app-engine-site-analytics-for-each-domain)

Ok, so I am testing out a marketing idea for this car mot company, buying 10 or so domains with key search words relating to the business (e.g carservice.com carmot.com hondaservice.com) and linking them all to one site, hosted on google app engine. I have got that bit to work and each domain displays the same site but I now want to get google analytics to show how many people clicked on each domain so I know if its worth renewing. If no one visits it, its not worth paying for. Is there a way I can send each domain to a different page hosted on the same app engine account? that way I could send it to a page which has a analytic code unique to the domain and then redirect it to the main site.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use an GA event that tells analytics what site they went to.
For example _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', Catagory, Action]) and put Catagory as "site" and action as the domain name ("carservice.com" or "carmot.com" or "hondaservice.com")

I think this way you can use GA to tell you how each site is doing and how people got to each site (keywords, direct link, marketing) and their bounce rate.

Comment: To get the domain name using java script you can use advice from this site: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/
This is a javascript specific solution to your problem which would be better than trying to serve multiple pages from app engine.