# Add domain to Google Appengine w/o using Google Apps for Business

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

I've tried to add a custom domain for my app, my own domain, instead of default `example.appspot.com`.

But just figured out that Google don't allow to use Google Apps for free anymore. Only Google Apps for Business.

Actually I don't need anything provided by Google Apps for Business, just need to use my own domain for my GAE project. But seems that now there no way to use custom domain w/o signin for Google Business account? and paying $50 a year. 
Is it correct? Is there any other way to add custom domain to GAE?

Comment: I believe if you register for the trial version and just let it expire (make sure your CC isn't autobilled) then the custom domain for GAE will continue to function though you won't be able to use other Google Apps services like Gmail. I have not fully tested this myself.

Comment: Heh, that's could be working :) But seems that there're no guarantie, I still hoping that there are more official way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** see comment from @JW.

> I just discovered today (as of 2014-04-11) a new custom domain
>   settings page is available from Google Developers Console:
>
> Go to https://console.developers.google.com/project Click on your
>   project On the left click "App Engine" Click "Settings" There you go!
>   You can configure custom domain without the need of Google App
>   account!

---

Register for Google Apps for Business and apply for $50 credit.

> Starting June 15 and for a limited time, Google will offer a USD
>   $50.00 App Engine credit for Google App Engine developers who have
>   recently purchased a new Google Apps for Business domain account for
>   their App Engine application.

https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1lSDA5Jol0Bosaop3RKZ9YqlSyzVLsCtAv8gYupBheR4/viewform

Comment: Thank you for the links. So, the official answer: Register for Google Apps for Business and apply for $50 credit.

Comment: Can you give link to place where you find this form?

Comment: @Chameleon It is the link in my answer.

Comment: @Loša You are inaccurate I asked about link in which link https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1lSDA5Jol0Bosaop3RKZ9YqlSyzVLsCtAv8gYupBheR4/viewform is found - where I can find page with this link?

Comment: @Chameleon Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I found it in this Google Group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/jC_K-YlmXhM/XPJYq1HUgusJ

Comment: Just so you know, Google has now added a "custom domain without GApps" feature. See the next answer.

Answer (score 2):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/23006209/8137:

> I just discovered today (as of 2014-04-11) a new custom domain settings page is available from Google Developers Console:
>
> 1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/project
> 2. Click on your project
> 3. On the left click "App Engine"
> 4. Click "Settings"
>
> There you go! You can configure custom domain without the need of Google App account!