# Is possible not configure Google App Engine custom domain without paying for Google Apps?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

I want set custom domain for Google App Engine without use Google Apps or setup free Google Apps account how to do it now - since only paid version is visible?

I read Google App Engine documentation that is possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add domain to Google Appengine w/o using Google Apps for Business](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17423889/add-domain-to-google-appengine-w-o-using-google-apps-for-business)

Comment: I will check if it duplicate calling Google support if it works it is duplicate if not it is not duplicate and previous answer is invalid. During registration progress I was not seen any 50$ discount.

Comment: Whatever the final cost, there is no way to have a custom domain without a Apps For Business Account.  Specific costs will change from time to time.  ie $50 credit is for a limited period.  It is a duplicate.

Comment: @TimHoffman Tanks for hint indeed no custom domain in GAE without GA - 50$ is ok for GAE but If I can get 50$ for year it is ok - why not :) I think that free GAE should be free to not close way for freelancers and beginners - it does not pay :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/23006209/8137:

> I just discovered today (as of 2014-04-11) a new custom domain settings page is available from Google Developers Console:
>
> 1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/project
> 2. Click on your project
> 3. On the left click "App Engine"
> 4. Click "Settings"
>
> There you go! You can configure custom domain without the need of Google App account!