# GAE add domain error

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a domain on my property that I would like to use for my google application.

I have tried to use "add domain" feature of app engine, but no matter what I do, it always ends up in showing me an uninformed error page:

"Solicitud incorrecta."
(Wrong request)

I have also tried to "Sign up for Google Apps" which leads me through a process of choosing between creating a new free subdomain or purchasing a new one (but I already have one), and in the end the same error message is shown.

The domain is currently being redirected to myappname.appspot.com as a workaround, but I would like to control the domain from gae.

Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Google app engine with my own domain (not subdomain)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-domain-not-subdomain)

Comment: @SamueleMattiuzzo I cannot follow step 2 in that answer, as it gives me the "wrong request" message