# Free Domain hosting using GAE (Google App Engine)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, web-applications, hosting, web-hosting

I have registered a new domain name with GODaddy.com
and i would like to host my domain for free. Assume the app is a basic HTML page.

I have referred http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TVv_8SuhaDw for configuring GAE
now How can i configure my domain name to map to the app deployed in GAE

Any info will be helpful. Thanks

=================================================================================
**Update 1**

I followed the steps as given in [How to use Google app engine with my own naked domain (not subdomain)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-domain-not-subdomain)

but when i try to add the domain name it is asking to sign up for "Apps for Business", which i don't think free of service

Is there any way to add domain name to GAE with free of cost

**Update 2**

After some search it seems google have stopped offering standard (free) edition of Google apps on 6th december 2012.

https://support.google.com/a/answer/2855120?hl=en

Is there any way to host a free domain through google service ?

Comment: have you looked at the post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-domain-not-subdomain)

Comment: @arajashe I think that can be expressed as an answer, at least if that solution still works (what upog should tell us).

Comment: No, Google app Engine is update, now it is not possible to host for free, I am planning to try with github for hosting free static pages

Comment: @upog: Ya we can host our website for free of cost in Google App Engine...It was not closed by Google, still it's there. Few Months before i tried it in Linux Platform(using Python) and hosted my website in GAE. Also i mingled the Host with my Own Domain(which was bought in Godaddy)

Comment: Ignore the bit about asking on Server Fault. You'd get shot down if you asked this there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, to sum the short answers up:

Google closed the door for "free" domain linking to Google App Angine domains slowly.

To link a domain to Google App Engine apps always a connected Google Apps account is necessary.

Google Apps free of cost was canceled last year with a few months time where it was possible to sign in for limited Google Apps version with just one sub-account (so only one mail account for your domain e.g.) and some more limitations.

But as far as I can see from comments and my research over the summer, the links mentioned in the posts about the limited version are no longer available.

So you have to use one of the alternatives like [CapeDwarf](http://www.jboss.org/capedwarf) (if you want to stick to the APIs) which is told to run happily on OpenShift. And being there you could also think about directly using the Paas Services of OpenShift or CloudBees for application where the "free of cost" feature is essential. I didn't find that too hard for [my personal stuff](https://github.com/mgoellnitz/tangram)

Answer (score -1):

You can register to "Apps for Business", it's free and gives you 50 email addresses and another number of nice things, free small apps hosting is one of them.

Comment: Apps for Business is not free - 5 USD / user per month