# Forward naked domains

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, yahoo

I recently purchased a domain with Yahoo Domains for my GAE app. Where I managed to get the domain mapped into my GAE account.

Now, since GAE does not support naked domains, I just placed the `CNAME` for `www` to point to Google App Engine.

Everything works fine now, i.e. my app can be accessed through `http://www.my-example-domain.com`

The problem is with naked domain (with Yahoo), I am trying to forward the naked domain `http://my-example-domain.com` to h`ttp://www.my-example-domain.com` however, the domain manager is complaining that the forward is not possible.

What could be the problem that forward is not possible? Also, is there a way to solve this in GAE management console, since Yahoo domain manager seems to not able to handle this.

Comment: Some DNS service providers can do a redirect' see if they can.

Comment: FWIW, naked domains are now supported: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-naked-domain-not-subdomain?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Please try to do the following changes from your Google Apps Admin Console.

> Go to this [URL](https://admin.google.com/AdminHome?fral=1#Domains:) for Domain Management Settings in Google Apps Console.
>
> Under the Domain Management. Click on change redirect and add **`www`**.example.com. Also check the attached screenshot for the same.

[image]

> Also follow the instructions provided in the URL **`change A record`** below change redirect url.
> After making these changes you will see the URL will get redirected automatically.

Comment: My domain is not registered with Google, but with Yahoo

Comment: Domain Registrar doesn't matters but whenever you need to link a GAE App with any Domain, you must have to register with Google Apps. Also follow the instructions in this URL https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/domain.