# How do I use a naked/apex domain with App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

How do I serve my App Engine app from a naked domain `http://example.com`? I don't want to redirect from `http://example.com` to `http://www.example.com`. I want serve from `http://example.com`.

Are there any reverse proxy services that would allow me to do this? I see CloudFlare has just released [CNAME flattening](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-CNAME-Flattening-RFC-compliant-support-for-CNAME-at-the-root) specifically to support naked domains. However I have tried to setup a CNAME record for `example.com` to `myapp.appspot.com` but it appears not to work. Maybe the new Google Cloud DNS would work?

What have others done to make this work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19833472/forward-naked-domains

Comment: I specifically do *not* want to forward/redirect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just discovered today (as of 2014-04-11) a new custom domain settings page is available from Google Developers Console:

1. Go to https://console.developers.google.com/project
2. Click on your project
3. On the left click "App Engine"
4. Click "Settings"

There you can have the option to add naked domain directly.

Comment: I can confirm this works. I had to completely disassociate my App Engine app ID and Google Apps service before it would work though.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for the confirmation. What precisely did you do to get this to work? Thanks.

Comment: UPDATE: I got it to work by going into my Google Apps account and deleting the GAE app, and in the GAE settings > Administration > Application Settings, at the very bottom under "Cloud Integration", I clicked Create to update it to the new style App. I fiddled with a few other settings too, but I think those were the key items.

Comment: Oh, and I disabled and reenabled the app in GAE Application Settings after updating it to the new style -- not sure if that was needed or not.