# Google App Engine - Naked Domain Issue

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, no-www

I have an application hosted on google app engine. Recently I bought a domain from a registrar who does not provide 301 redirects to www. I looked around and found that to be able to use the naked domain with google app engine(as the discontinued support for naked domains) I have to either do 301 redirects or edit the .htaccess file. Can I do this with a google app engine app given it's not Apache? If not, what is any work around for this, specially if I don't want to transfer my domain to another service?

Basically my site works as `www.mysite.com` but I want `mysite.com` to work too and a 301 redirect from mysite.com to `www.mysite.com` is not provided by my registrar and GAE doesn't allow naked domains.

Comment: Could you use a third-party DNS service that supports domain forwarding?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Google app engine with my own naked domain (not subdomain)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-naked-domain-not-subdomain)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add 4 A-records into your DNS and configure naked redirect in google apps.
Step by step guide here:https://support.google.com/a/answer/2518373

Comment: I think this is outdated :/

Comment: Works fine for me right now. https://admin.google.com/example.com/AdminHome?chromeless=1#OGX:DomainSettingsChangeNakedRedirect