# How to map a custom domain to an app-engine app via Cloud DNS api?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-dns

Is there any documentation to explain how to map a custom domain to an app hosted on App Engine and solely via Cloud DNS API or any other Google Cloud API?

I've already added a CNAME record for the "www.my-domain.com." pointing to "ghs.googlehosted.com.", and I've set the name server addresses I've received from the Cloud DNS, on my domain registrar account. But I still get a 404 on a google server (a 404 page with google logo, etc).

[Update]: As I've mentioned in my other reply on this thread, Amazon Route53 service has a specific kind of "alias" DNS record which you can map a domain to any resource on AWS (load balancer, EC2 instance, etc). But I can't find any such DNS mapping on Google Cloud for an app hosted on App Engine.

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Google app engine with my own domain (not subdomain)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-domain-not-subdomain)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The thread you've mentioned discusses almost the same topic BUT all is handled through the web console. What I want to do is solely via the DNS api.

Answer (score 0):

You've completed half the steps actually, as Jarod pointed out, you also need to register your domain in the web console.

The Cloud DNS service takes care of specifying where traffic meant for your CNAME should go. Registering your domain in the web console will essentially tell Google when receiving traffic from `www.my-domain.com.` to redirect it to `your-app.appspot.com`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I was actually thinking the same because there was no API equivalent for mapping a custom domain to an app-engine resource (e.g. Amazon's Route 53 service has a special kind of, non-standard, alias DNS record for such mapping).  I actually want to handle the entire process via the API so that I can automate this. Even a single manual web console interaction will prevent this to happen in the code.  I still truly appreciate your reply.

Comment: i'd definitely like to have this feature as well, that opens up a lot of possibilities for google app engine

Comment: Yeah this is silly. This is the sole issue holding up multi-tenant apps on appengine. I'm glad they moved the custom domains from Gapps but wouldn't it be lovely to just have your customers throw a cname at your appspot url and be done?