# Google cloud api for mapping custom domains to app

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-dns

Is there an sort of API to automatically map custom domains to app. In a multi tenant system, app domain mapping requires that an explicit mapping is created through App Engine settings. 
[image]

Is there any way of doing this programmatically? Cloud DNS API of sort for App Engine app domain mapping.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Not possible. Domains ownership validation process is manual. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25275749/how-to-map-a-custom-domain-to-an-app-engine-app-via-cloud-dns-api. However I came across a Google team running alpha tests on possibilities of managing custom domain via API, the feature might satisfy some of your requirements. Sign up here [https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSfixtu8XQRNSAIo-mCaHnrHsUJLcMj0cSjI_jMskP7YpgN0vA/viewform?c=0&w=1](1) to gain access to feature

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile the desired feature has been implemented in beta stage, and there is now indeed a way of doing this programmatically, and you can now manage both your custom domains and SSL certificates using the new beta features of the Admin API and gcloud command-line tool. More detail can be gathered from the "App Engine users, now you can configure custom domains from the API or CLI" documentation [page](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/06/App-Engine-users-now-you-can-configure-custom-domains-from-the-API-or-CLI.html).