# Google App Engine Custom Domain verified, but not showing in "Select domain to point to" list

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps

ANSWER: My company www. domain name was registered with "Google Docs" Sites.  I removed it according to these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2494299/1160870

---

The www. website is currently working on a non-Google host, where the domain name is parked.  My companies domain name is associated with a "Google Docs" account, and its MX DNS records point to "Google Docs" for email.

I created a new website using App Engine, accessible at http://**myapp**.appspot.com/

I cant make the new appspot.com site work with my companies www. domain name.

I log into https://console.developers.google.com/ and go to:
Compute > App Engine > Settings > Custom Domain
I have Verified my custom domain name, but it is not showing up in the list.

If I go to my Google Docs "Admin Console" and choose "App Engine Apps", I can see the new website app in the list.  But if I try to "Add New Url" and point to the companies www. domain name, it fails saying: "Already used, please remove previous mapping first".

Many thanks for any advice you can give.

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER: My company www. domain name was registered with "Google Docs" Sites. I removed it according to these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2494299/1160870