# Naked domain not working for GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I am struggling to get my naked domain to work with GAE.

The domain has been verified and I have set the A and AAAA records as instructed, but its just not working.

Doing a DNS lookup on the domain fails to show the A and AAAA records, but there were definitely added.

Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: What's the domain and the TTL? Did you add the domain in the App Engine settings?

Comment: Domain added in the settings and verified. Not sure on the TTL, where can I find that?

Comment: The TTL is set wherever your DNS is hosted. When you updated your A and AAAA records there should be a place to set the TTL. It's set in seconds. It may take up to that much time to propagate and update DNS everywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Google app engine with my own naked domain (not subdomain)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-naked-domain-not-subdomain)