# Naked and www custom domains with Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, cname, a-records

I have added two custom domains to Google Developers Console for a Google App Project. One, a naked domain with A and AAA records set on the third party DNS manager as specified by Google. Two, a www domain with a Cname record set on the third party DNS manager, as specified by Google.

The www is serving, but the naked domain is not! The A records ip addresses timeout on my local machine but I get results when using http://tools.pingdom.com/ping/

Obviously you can use more than one custom domain but is there something I'm missing here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Google app engine with my own naked domain (not subdomain)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-naked-domain-not-subdomain)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** custom naked domain mapping is now supported directly in GAE, see [How to use Google app engine with my own naked domain (not subdomain)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-naked-domain-not-subdomain?rq=1).

[Old answer follows]

If it's acceptable for you to use custom domains through Google Apps then you can use the [Google Admin console](https://admin.google.com/) to:

- map your naked domain to Google Apps
- redirect the naked domain to a certain (sub)domain of your choice

I find several advantages of going this way:

- you can change the naked domain redirect without any change in the
  GAE apps domain configs
- the direct domain mapping of GAE apps (without using Google Apps) is
  still very young, documentation is far from exhaustive
- you can use SSL with your custom domains, according to [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain):
  "To add Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption (i.e., an HTTPS
  address) to your App Engine app, you must use the SSL service
  provided with Google Apps".

Comment: Dan, thanks for this. I have already considered using Google Apps but held off as I was told by a Google Support Tech that SSL would be available in the developers console directly by the end of August, therefore decided to avoid the use and extra burden of Google Apps until I had checked that new functionality out. What is clear, is that the Turkish authorities have blocked the following ip addresses, I suspect as part of a block of Google ip addresses. 216.239.32.21
216.239.34.21
216.239.36.21
216.239.38.21.

Comment: I will now have to reconsider my options. At the moment I have a www domain running fine as this has a Cname record in my DNS setup, but the naked domain has A records containing the ips listed.