# Setting up custom domain with www on appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, dns

I've set up a custom domain with Appengine.

The domain currently works as http://example.com (naked domain) but it throws a "This webpage is not available" error  with http://www.example.com

Any idea how could I get the 'www' subdomain working? Would it be possible to fix it by adding/changing the DNS records (CNAME, TXT)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Google app engine with my own domain (not subdomain)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-domain-not-subdomain)

Answer (score 1):

**The procedure is as follows:**

1. Navigate to
   https://console.developers.google.com/project/yourapp/appengine/settings/domains,
   **having replaced "yourapp" with your project name.**
2. Click "**Add custom Domain**"
3. Go to the 2nd section (it will say "**Select the domain you want to point to *yourapp***").
4. In that section, select the 2nd field, fill in "**www**" and **select the domain in the dropdown**.
5. Log in to your DNS management dashboard (this could be godaddy.com, namecheap.com, etc).
6. Add a **CNAME** record with your DNS host, as follows: **alias: "www"**, address (**canonical name**): **ghs.googlehosted.com**, and save.
7. Give it a few minutes, and **www.yoursite.com** should now take you to your app (should be the same that can be found at **yourapp.appspot.com**).

*Assumptions I made:*

- That you wish to point the DNS record to the **default module** of your AppEngine project. Please leave a comment if you wish 'www' to point to a different module.
- That you have already registered your domain with Google and have a **TXT DNS** record there, proving your ownership of the domain to Google.