# How do I use my Google App with my a custom domain?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, subdomain

I've looked at previous questions [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-naked-domain-not-subdomain?rq=1), but they use the GSuite Administrator to make changes, while my app uses GCloud. The domain registrar is separate since Google domains don't work in my country.

I mainly followed this guide to setting up my Zones and updating the name servers. I've configured the

https://cloud.google.com/dns/docs/update-name-servers

The question I linked to earlier recommended setting up a `www.` subdomain, but it used Authenticator. I'm not sure how to do this in a zone. I set up all the records properly in my domain registrar.

Here are the settings:

[image]

When I load the site itself (There's no actual HTTP response code):

[image]

And when I try the www. subdomain

[image]

I'm sure there's a step I'm missing, but this is my first site with GCloud. So I'm not very familiar with the process.

Answer (score 1):

I think where is your missing step.

When you ask Google to use your domain, Google will expose HTTPS endpoint. HTTPS requires a certificate, and Google will generate it for you. However, before doing this, Google has to be sure that the domain belong to you.

You have to prove to google that you own your domain. For this, go to [this page](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home?hl=en), log in and add a property (your website URL). Follow the instruction and be sure that your property has been validated.

Then, wait some minutes (hours?) the time that the certificates are generated and deployed.

Comment: Thanks Guillaume, I'll try that

Comment: Let me know if it works. Else, we will try to find something else!

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I don't think this is an ownership verification issue. I changed the zone/record IP address and it raised a 404 error, meaning that the domain is getting through to Google. I changed it back and it continued to not work  :-).

Comment: Is there any way I can verify that it's an ownership verification issue? (the domain name registrar doesn't have a CPanel)

Comment: Here you have a detailed guide on how to verify this - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#adding_a_custom_domain_for_your_application . Could you please come back with a response after you have followed it ? Was the issue related to this ?