# Google app engine given me default domain name how to change it?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

Google app engine has given me a default domain name(https://myproject-name.uc.r.appspot.com/). How to add my purchased domain instead of this domain name?
The image link is given below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ijw3V.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use Google App Engine with my own naked domain (not subdomain)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/817809/how-to-use-google-app-engine-with-my-own-naked-domain-not-subdomain)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a custom domain. To use a custom domain, map the domain to your app, then update your DNS records.  You can map a naked domain, such as example.com or a subdomain, such as subdomain.example.com. You can also use wildcards to map subdomains.

Something to keep in mind is that if you do not have a domain, you must purchase one and in case you are using a Load Balancer to route your traffic to your App Engine, it is recommended to map your custom domain to the LB instead the directly to your App.

At this [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains#mapping_a_custom_domain_to_your_app) you can find the necessaries steps to map your custom domain to your app.